# How to dynamically build resources in CDK based on a config file?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have two AWS accounts :

- **Account 1**
- **Account 2**

The below config file is stored in an S3 bucket in **Account 1**. The size of this config file is more than 4 kb even when compressed. (AWS Custom Resources have a limit of 4 kb response)

Sample Config File:

```
{
  {"application":"app1", "type":"test"}
  {"application":"app2", "type":"test2"}
}
```

In the CDK code for **Account 2** I want to create a CloudWatch dashboard for each of the applications in JSON file.

Is it possible to read this JSON file from CDK by making an SDK call ?

Comment: Sure. Just read the JSON file using your CDK language's tools.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Be sure to consider the JSON update side-effects and ensure each new config version is updated in source control.  What is the JSON update data flow?  How does the SDK come into the picture?  Just reading the JSON file (e.g. with `fs.readFileSync`) is probably necessary, but is likely not sufficient to align with CDK [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).

Comment: The JSON file is stored in a S3 bucket in **Account 1**. Based on this JSON file I want to created resources in **Account 2** using CDK.